# Firebase Nodejs wrong return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner at node and firebase and I don't get how to get the right value for the output here. 
In the console i get the right value but the return value is undifiend.

```
function Emoji() {

var ref = firebase.database().ref('users').child('9ifrkEw7YjSRGtiaFFHT1rzieDA2');

this.getEmoji = function () {
    ref.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val().emoji); //displays the value from database 
        return  String(snapshot.val().emoji); //displays undefiened
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not an expert at either but it looks like you're trying to cast an emoji object to a string?

Comment: the type of snapshot.val().emoji is a string... actually i don't need the cast

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is actually just returning from the anonymous function that you passed to `then()`.  It's not returning from `this.getEmoji`.  When you call `getEmoji`, it's going to return *immediately*, and some time later your database query will generate a result.  The database query is *asynchronous*, so you should probably make `getEmoji` asynchronous as well by returning a promise that's resolved with the result of your query.  The caller of `getEmoji` can use that promise's then() method to receive the result.